# Boost libraries not installed with Homebrew: invalid option: --c++11

Tags: boost, homebrew

This is the syntax that I always used to install boost on my mac using Homebrew:

`brew install boost --c++11 --universal --link=static --runtime-link=static`

Today, I update my Homebrew and I am no longer able to install boost. It states: "Error: invalid option: --c++11"; "invalid option: --universal"; etc.

Same with:
`brew install boost --with-c++11 --universal --link=static --runtime-link=static`

Can someone please advise what has changed and how this can be fixed? OS Catalina, version 10.15.7.

EDIT: I have never used MacPorts before. What would be the correct syntax to install a static boost library supporting c++11 using it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that those options are no longer needed. I compiled the library just like `brew install boost`, and the library was universal, static and c++11 compatible.